# Using a list objects to look up items in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a a wxPython checklist box that returns a list of integers. I want to use the integers to look up items in a dictionary. I am not really sure the best way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of all dictionary items that those integers map to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you asking for

```
[ someDict[k] for k in someList ]
```

?

Comment: That was it, still getting used to list comprehension. Thank you.